# vscode spaces ? filter open files by language / file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

With VSCODE; working in a PHP / JS project I would like to selectively display / hide opened files by extension or detected language.

Is it possible ?

this would for me avoid distraction; differentiate back from front and avoid clutter.

Comment: Why not just open the same folder in two windows- one for frontend and one for backend? Or have two editor groups- one for backend and one for frontend, and maximize the editor group and switch between them (whichever one is focused will be automatically maximized)? Are those options not satisfactory to you? Or did you just not think of them?